# Tailwind CSS Navigation Hover Dropdown with Padding

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm attempting to show the sub `<ul>` list on the first navigation item when the item is hovered:

[image]

Everything is working except for sometimes (it's hit and miss) when you are in between the padding of the first line `<ul>` item and the sub `<ul>` item, the secondary `<ul>` will disappear:

[image]

How can I keep the secondary navigation list open when I'm navigating from the dropdown to the item list?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neakspuL/)

```
<ul class="w-full">
    <li class="dropdown inline px-4 text-purple-500 hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer font-bold text-base uppercase tracking-wide">
        <a>Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu absolute hidden h-auto flex pt-4">
            <ul class="block w-full bg-white shadow px-12 py-8">
                <li class="py-1"><a class="block text-purple-500 font-bold text-base uppercase hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer">Item</a></li>
                <li class="py-1"><a class="block text-purple-500 font-bold text-base uppercase hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="py-1"><a class="block text-purple-500 font-bold text-base uppercase hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer">Item 3</a></li>
                <li class="py-1"><a class="block text-purple-500 font-bold text-base uppercase hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer">Item 4</a></li>
                <li class="py-1"><a class="block text-purple-500 font-bold text-base uppercase hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer">Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="inline px-4 text-purple-500 hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer font-bold text-base uppercase tracking-wide"><a>Non-Dropdown</a></li>
    <li class="inline px-4 text-purple-500 hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer font-bold text-base uppercase tracking-wide"><a>Non-Dropdown</a></li>
    <li class="inline px-4 text-purple-500 hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer font-bold text-base uppercase tracking-wide lg:pr-8"><a>Non-Dropdown</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Tailwind Group

You can use **group** and **group-hover** they are pretty simple and handy

Here is the full code example: [tailwind-playgroud](https://play.tailwindcss.com/YfSw9fCrxG)

Step 1 add **group** and **relative** classes to the div that wraps the dropdown

```html
<li class="group relative dropdown  px-4 text-purple-500 hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer font-bold text-base uppercase tracking-wide">
  <a>Dropdown</a>
```

Step 2 add **group-hover:block** to the div that wraps the dropdown links

```html
<div class="group-hover:block dropdown-menu absolute hidden h-auto">
```

Step 3 add **top-0** to the ul that wraps the dropdown links

```html
<ul class="top-0 w-48 bg-white shadow px-6 py-8">
    <li class="py-1"><a class="block text-purple-500 font-bold text-base uppercase hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer">Item</a></li>
    <li class="py-1"><a class="block text-purple-500 font-bold text-base uppercase hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="py-1"><a class="block text-purple-500 font-bold text-base uppercase hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="py-1"><a class="block text-purple-500 font-bold text-base uppercase hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer">Item 4</a></li>
    <li class="py-1"><a class="block text-purple-500 font-bold text-base uppercase hover:text-purple-700 cursor-pointer">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Step 4 This is last step  add display: ['group-hover'] in the **tailwind.config.js** file inside **variants**

```js
variants: {
 display:['group-hover']
}
```

Comment: Your suggession works 100%. My question is, what if, I need a submenu for a dropdown menu item, as if I put again 'group' & 'group-hover:block' ithe submenu appears before the 'onmouseover' of relevant dropdown item...

Comment: @GajenDissanayake I am not sure what version of tailwind you have been using but if you check the documentation, you will find a section: "Differentiating nested groups"
where it explains how you can name groups and differentiate between them.
Below you have an example of the above code, in which I have added another sub menu:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/I7fG01zSOE

Comment: Wow, Thanks for letting me know the "Differentiation nested groups" I assumed there should be a way because submenus are very common in navbars. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

**3** changes. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a87s1pmq/)

- Add **relative** class to the `li` tag.
- Add **top-0** with the `dropdown-menu absolute` class.
- Change the padding of `ul`, inside the menu, to `p-8`. Just a minor css

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this issue: transparent div between

Example (assuming mt-2 from dropdown menu to trigger):

```
<div className="group">
    <button>Dropdown button</button>
    <div className="hidden group-hover:block -mt-4">
      <div className="mt-6 bg-transparent">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      <ul>
    </div>
</div>
```