# Tailwind nav-bar dropdown disappears before selection can be made

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a navbar with a profile picture. When the mouse is hovered over the profile picture, I want a drop down menu to appear allowing the user to select Log Out link. The problem now is, the pop up works when the mouse hovers over the profile picture. Soon as the mouse leaves the profile picture to do a selection, the drop down menu disappears.

I have followed the advice from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056034/tailwind-css-navigation-hover-dropdown-with-padding) using the group and group-hover, still my issue persists. I am new to Tailwindcss and below is my full html template code:

```
<nav class="bg-sky-50">
  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <img class="block w-auto h-[13rem] lg:hidden" src="{{company.company_logo.url}}" alt="Pokestop logo">
    <img class="hidden w-auto h-[13rem] lg:block" src="{{company.company_logo.url}}" alt="Pokestop logo">
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-wrap mx-5">
    <div class="flex space-x-4">
      <a href="#" class="bg-gray-900 text-white rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium" aria-current="page">
        Bestil Pakker
      </a>

      <a href="#" class="text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium">
        Søg Kort
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="ml-auto">
      {% if userAuthenticated %}
      <div class="group relative ml-3" id="user-profile">
        <button type="button"
          class="flex rounded-full bg-gray-800 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800"
          id="user-menu-button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
          <span class="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
          <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
            alt="">
        </button>

        <div class="absolute top-10 right-0 bg-white w-48 py-2 rounded-md shadow-xl z-10 group-hover:block hidden"
          id="userMenu">
          <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100">Log out</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <div class="relative ml-3">
        <a href="#" class="bg-green-800 text-lime-100 px-3 py-2 rounded-md hover:text-gray-400 text-lg"
          aria-current="page">
          Log In
        </a>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the group-hover to one level up with a separate div tag. It now works as expected.

```
<nav class="bg-sky-50">
  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <img class="block w-auto h-[13rem] lg:hidden" src="{{company.company_logo.url}}" alt="Pokestop logo">
    <img class="hidden w-auto h-[13rem] lg:block" src="{{company.company_logo.url}}" alt="Pokestop logo">
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-wrap mx-5">
    <div class="flex space-x-4">
      <a href="#" class="bg-gray-900 text-white rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium" aria-current="page">
        Bestil Pakker
      </a>

      <a href="#" class="text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium">
        Søg Kort
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="ml-auto">
      {% if userAuthenticated %}
      <div class="group relative ml-3" id="user-profile">
        <button type="button"
          class="flex rounded-full bg-gray-800 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800"
          id="user-menu-button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
          <span class="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
          <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
            alt="">
        </button>
        <div class="group-hover:block dropdown-menu absolute hidden h-auto">
          <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 bg-white w-48 py-2 rounded-md shadow-xl z-10">
            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100">Log out</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <div class="relative ml-3">
        <a href="#" class="bg-green-800 text-lime-100 px-3 py-2 rounded-md hover:text-gray-400 text-lg"
          aria-current="page">
          Log In
        </a>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```